# InfoPath Form Naming Methods

Tags: infopath

I want to know some different methods of naming your InfoPath forms when they are submitted.

The current problem we are experiencing in our office is that the File Name of the form is a concatenation of a field on our form and the date.

If the user changes the field, a duplicate form would be created with a different file name, but the exact same information.

In another library I am able to create a form with a unique identifier and title, which is not dependent on any fields.

What are some methods others use for giving names to form? What are some ways to avoid this other than mentioned?

I want opinions, suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Simple procedure I used 'once upon time':

1. add additional field to your form and call it `filename`
2. when saving form check if `filename` contains value

   - if true (new form) create one using some logic to keep it unique and put it in field `filename`
   - if false (existing form) use it's value to save form and avoid duplicates

By doing this you are able to use dates and/or times for file names.

Comment: This is the process most people do. Just configure the library to allow overwrites when you save the form and you'll be golden.

Comment: I have been performing this same thing with my forms as well, except I haven't been passing a field that contains a string value to the "hidden" field.

Comment: With SP, I bet this is the only way to preserve the forms...curious to see what others do. If there are other ways :)